# Joomla and AJAX

Tags: ajax, joomla

I'm having a terrible time trying to get the ajax call below working in my Joomla 3.6 component. The javascript function below works in the sense that it does return the data and display it in the page--for a split second--then the page reloads, and I get the result of view.html.php, which is not what I need here. I get the same results whether I set the async property to true or false. It just happens much quicker with async set to true. The data returned in view.raw.php is fine. I must avoid reloading view.html.php. The javascript function getCase() is called by "onclick" of a button and I always clear the cache before testing.
Thanks.

```
    function getCase(getDataVal) 
{
    var examcaseid = ($('examcase_id')) ? $('examcase_id').value : -1;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php?option=com_casecreator&view=examcase&format=raw&layout=edit&id='+examcaseid+'&getdata='+getDataVal,
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: 'text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"',
        async: true,
        success: function (data, status, jq) {
            $('rc_xml_display').innerHTML = data;
            //alert('In getCase(), rc_xml_display is: '+$('rc_xml_display').innerHTML);
        },
        error: function (jq, status, e) {
            alert('Unable to retrieve case.'+JSON.stringify(jq));
        }
    });

    return;
}
```

Entire display() function from view.raw.php:

```
    public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $app            = JFactory::getApplication();
    $getdata        = $app->input->get('getdata');
    $case_index     = !empty($app->getUserState('case_index')) ? $app->getUserState('case_index') : 0;

    if ($getdata == 'nextcase' || $getdata == 'previouscase' || $getdata == 'initialcase') {
        $app->setUserState('active_tab', 'browsecases');
        $cases_arr = $app->getUserState('rc_cases');

        switch ($getdata) {
            case 'nextcase':        $case_index++; break;
            case 'previouscase':    $case_index--; break;
            case 'initialcase':     $case_index = 0; break;
            case 'default':         break;
        }
        if ($case_index < 0) {
            $case_index = 0; 
            $msg = 'You have reached the first case in the result set.';
            $app->enqueueMessage($msg, 'warning');
        }
        if ($case_index >= count($cases_arr)) {
            $case_index = count($cases_arr)-1;
            $msg = 'You have reached the last case in the result set.';
            $app->enqueueMessage($msg, 'warning');
        }

        if ( !empty($cases_arr[$case_index]) ) {
            $app->setUserState('case_index', $case_index);
            $app->setUserState('current_case', $cases_arr[$case_index]);
        }

        header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
        print $app->getUserState('current_case');
        $app->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you called the url manually? Does it contain a html/head/body tag? There are some plugins out there which cause problems with the format=raw url parameter and render full HTML pages instead.

Comment: The html data is actually a fragment generated in the PHP code, so it's not a full document called with a URL.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page: the document you load by this ajax url does not contain anything else than your data? Is the behavior different if you use $('rc_xml_display').html(data); or leaf comment this line out?

Comment: No, that didn't help at all. Using $('rc_xml_display').html(data);  actually ended up not displaying the expected data, even for the split second I get it when using innerHTML. I really don't believe the problem is with the javascript. I believe it's with the way the Joomla MVC framework handles AJAX requests, because the data is returned to the AJAX call exactly as I expect it to be returned. Then the page reloads view.html.php. That is what I don't want to happen.

Comment: Calling  $('rc_xml_display') makes actually no sense since 'rc_xml_display' is not a valid seletor. I would expect #rc_xml_display or something like this. Do you have a site where one can see this behavior?

Comment: You know, I realized that you are right about the selectors. Oddly enough, adding the # breaks the javascript. I get the values without it, not with. I must have a different version of jQuery than you do. I believe we have jQuery 1.7.1 . Still, the javascript is not the problem as all the values are good in the call to getCase(). It's the page reload of view.html.php.

Comment: I'm afraid without seeing this myself I can't provide any help. Let me know if there is a link to check this out

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you're doing it the ideal way. Please follow our simple guide [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-use-joomlas-ajax-interface-component-com_ajax) for using the Joomla Ajax component.

In any case, your "examcase" view should have a die() immediately after echoing the data so as not to transfer control elsewhere (please let me know if you need more explanation on this).

Comment: I assume by "die" you mean close() which I definitely have included:
[code]
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
  print $app->getUserState('current_case');
  $app->close();
 [code]

Comment: No - die means `die();`.

Comment: Also, since this is a custom component, and my understanding of the Joomla MVC framework is "one component per page" I don't really see how I would use com_ajax in conjunction with my component, but I'll read the page you posted.

Comment: The other AJAX calls I've implemented in this application worked perfection well with
  JFactory::getApplication()->close();

Comment: Once you finish echoing the data (where you are echoing it), add a `die();` at the end. Try it.

Comment: Well I tried die(); and it did not work whether I added it after close(); or instead of close(); . The  page continues to reload view.html.php and give me the original data instead if the new data even though the new data is clearly being returned. When I uncomment the alert statement above, I get the new data in the alert, click OK, see it in the page for a split second, and then the page reloads and displays the original data.